# Inputting multiple floats using cin ERROR

Tags: c++, input, cin, cascading

I want to input 5 `float` values consecutively but the program is not working properly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float v, i, vr, vl, vc, r, xl, xc, z;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the values of v,i,vr,vl,vc" << endl;
        cin >> v;
        cin >> i;
        cin >> vr;
        cin >> vl;
        cin >> vc;
        cout << endl << v << " " << i << " " << vr << " " << vl << " " << vc << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I try entering the input as 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 , the program only accepts four values

The output is:
1.1 2 0.2 3.3 4.4

Please tell me where I am going wrong and how do I correct my code.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a space or non visible character between the first `2` and the `.` in `2.2`?

Comment: Yes I am sure that there is nothing between the 2 and the .

Comment: The code works perfectly fine, just tried it myself.

Comment: Could you tell me how you separated the numbers , and which IDE you use? @ABusyProgrammer

Comment: Post actual, compilable code, and a the contents of a text file containing your input.

Comment: #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main(){

 float v,i,vr,vl,vc,r,xl,xc,z;

 for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
    cout<<"Enter the values of v,i,vr,vl,vc"<<endl;
    cin>>v;
    cin>>i;
    cin>>vr;
    cin>>vl;
    cin>>vc;

   cout<<endl<<v<<" "<<i<<" "<<vr<<" "<<vl<<" "<<vc<<endl;
 
 }
 return 0;
 }

Comment: @NeilButterworth I first inputted the numbers as 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 ie the numbers separated by spaces and then pressed enter . Then i tried by typing the numbers and pressing enter after each number , in this method , the output was displayed after I pressed enter after the FOURTH number . The output was same using both methods

Comment: I used cpp.sh as the compiler, however, with the code you had earlier posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `i` as `float` in outer scope and then using `it` as `int` in inner scope.
So when you input

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5
```

Using

```
cin>>v;
cin>>i; 
cin>>vr; 
cin>>vl; 
cin>>vc;
```

It only takes `2` from `2.2` and then takes 0.2 for vr variable.

So variable values become

```
v=1.1
i=2
vr=0.2
vl=3.3
vc=4.4
```

Hence 5.5 is left because it take 2.2 as 2 inputs

> Solution:

Change your `for` loop variable to `j`.

Comment: Also, being `int i` the loop counter, it makes undefined (dependent from input values) the number of repetitions of that loop itself.

Comment: Thank you @user64322 , your answer helped me a lot . I will be careful in the future

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable name conflict in your code:

```
float v, i, vr, vl, vc, r, xl, xc, z; // Here, variable "i" is declared as a floating-point variable

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) // Here, "i" is declared again, this time as an int
```

When there are multiple variables of the same names, but in different scopes of the code, then the compiler uses the variable that is local to the scope at that point. That causes the error; you want the variable `i` to store the value `2.2` input, however, the most local variable is the counter `i` of the for-loop. Hence, the compiler tries to store the value in the counter. Since the counter is of type `int`, the `2.2` is broken up; counter `i` stores 2, and `vr` stores the `0.2`.

That is why your compiler only accepts 4 values; the second value input is divided between 2 variables.

To correct this, change the name of the counter variable for your for-loop:

```
float v, i, vr, vl, vc, r, xl, xc, z;
for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) // The name of the counter variable is changed from "i" to "j"
{
    cout << "Enter the values of v,i,vr,vl,vc" << endl;
    cin >> v;
    cin >> i;
    cin >> vr;
    cin >> vl;
    cin >> vc;
    cout << endl << v << " " << i << " " << vr << " " << vl << " " << vc << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, change the name of the variable `i` (the one that has a scope outside the for-loop) to some other name:

```
float v, num, vr, vl, vc;
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the values of v,j,vr,vl,vc" << endl;
    cin >> v;
    cin >> num;
    cin >> vr;
    cin >> vl;
    cin >> vc;
    cout << endl << v << " " << num << " " << vr << " " << vl << " " << vc << endl;
}
```